# Cannot set cookie to expire on browser close

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

I'm trying to set a cookie using javascript so it expires when the browser is closed.

I have the following function to do that:

```
function createCookie(value,days) {
    var name = "name";
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    var cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    document.cookie = cookie;
}
```

I tried many ways found here and there on the web like setting the date to "", setting it to yesterday (in that case the cookie is not even added) and omitting "expires" completly. I tried on Firefox and Chrome checking that every process was stopped before opening again, but the cookie is alway there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function for my self. It will work for you i gess :)

```
function createCookie(name, value, expiresInX_days, path) {
        var a = new Date;
        var expires = expiresInX_days || 1;
        a.setTime(Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * expires));
        var pt = path ? " ; path=" + path + ";" : ";";
        return (document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";" + "expires=" + a.toUTCString() + pt) ? !0 : !1;
}
```

Comment: what do I have to pass for expiresInX_days for it to be deleted on browser close?

Comment: If you dont set expire time on your browser, it will deleted in browsers default time. You have to add name, value, expires date and path. Dont forget the path :) Its important :)

Comment: I'm using it like this: `createCookie('name','value',null,'/')`  but it doesn't get deleted

Comment: I answer you from other answer :) You can see at the next answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete your cookie, you can use this:

```
function rmCookie(cookieName){
    var a = new Date;
    a.setTime(0);
    return (document.cookie = cookieName + "=;" + a.toUTCString()) ? !0 : !1;
}
```

If you want get your cookie clean,

```
function getMyFuckingCookie(cookieName){
    var a = document.cookie.replace(/; /g, ";").split(";"),
        b = a.length,
        c = {},
        nm = cookieName || !1;
    while (b--) {
        var d = a[b].split(/=(.+)/);
        c[d[0]] = d[1];
    }
    return (nm) ? c[nm] : c;
}
```